# how to change domain in kiwiTCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have been looking for a way to change the host in kiwiTCMS, but unfortunately i could not find any solution online

how can I change the domain in kiwiTCMS from localhost to another host

Comment: Does the answer from @Prome help or you mean how to configure your FQDN for which you just need to point your DNS to the IP address of the docker container running Kiwi TCMS.

Answer (score 2):

Login with superuser / administrator account to Kiwi instance and do the following:

1. Click on **Admin**
2. Click on **Everything else**
3. Click on  **Sites** (or directly via https://localhost/admin/sites/site/1/change/ )
4. Click on **localhost**
5. Input **Domain name** and Display name
6. Click on  **Save**

See documentation: https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-kiwi-base-url